# click handler is called before nested knockout form submit handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

I have a clickable div which is hooked up with bootstrap collapse plugin to show/hide its collapsible content. Inside this div, there's a form which has a knockout submit-handler. When i'm clicking the submit-button in the form, the click-handler for the collapse is called before the knockout submit-handler is.

```
<div data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse1">
  ...
  <form data-bind="submit: submitForm">
    <input type="number" />
    <input type="submit" />
  </form>
</div>

<div class="collapse" id="collapse1">
  ...
</div>
```

As of my understanding, the click-handler for the collapse is bound to the document (if you take a look at the collapse data-api), and the knockout submit-handler is bound to the form element. If you click the submit-button (or pressing enter in the input), shouldn't the submit-event reach the submit-handler first? As of the form is the closest parent from the point of origin?

```
 $(document).on('click.bs.collapse.data-api', '[data-toggle="collapse"]', function (e){
 ...
 })
```

My question: **Why is the click-handler of the collapse called before the knockout submit-handler?**

see jsfiddle for a better example: https://jsfiddle.net/knekk/oocxfgmq/

Answer (score 0):

You have bind toggle event to div element.

Try above code

```js
var viewModel = function() {
  this.formSubmit = function(){
   alert('submit');
  };
  
  $('#collapse1').on('show.bs.collapse', function(e){
   alert('show content');
  }).on('hide.bs.collapse', function(e){
   alert('hide content');
  });
};

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="list-group-item list-group-item-danger" >
    <div class="row form-inline">
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <strong>Collapse</strong>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 text-right">
        <form data-bind="submit: formSubmit">
          <input type="number" />
          <input type="submit" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse1" />
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Collapse content -->
  <div class="collapse" id="collapse1">
    <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, cum etiam labitur diceret id, ex sale omnium neglegentur cum. Ad nec eirmod definiebas argumentum, eam te oratio disputando. In errem volumus cum, virtute platonem persequeris ei quo. Ex has reformidans consequuntur. Consetetur cotidieque et mea, in qui bonorum blandit.

Nemore essent his an. Te hinc wisi consulatu usu, fuisset conceptam ius cu. Eam id mazim altera argumentum. At ridens moderatius his, in posse tollit moderatius vim, in vel dico recteque. Cum illum dissentias in, ex stet aliquip salutatus eum.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but that was my old fiddle version. I've updated the jsfiddle. And you should still be able to open the collapse by clicking the div. My question is why the submit-event is fired after the click-event.

Comment: In all browsers, except IE<9, there are two stages of event processing.

The event first goes down - that’s called capturing, and then bubbles up. This behavior is standartized in W3C specification.

W3C elements events order 

Captures down - through "Parent" -> "Child" -> "Grand Child"
Bubbles up - through "Grand Child" -> "Child" -> "Parent"

Comment: Yes indeed, then shouldn't the submit-handler be called first though? as of the closest parent of the initial submit/click? If you look in the collapse plugin, the click-handler is attached to the document, not the div? Is the click-event raised and reaching the document before the submit-event is raised?

Answer (score 0):

Your event is bubbling. JQuery has got event binded to the div, inside which your KO is firing another. So jquery > knockout, in that particular order of click events.

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html

You could also "hack" it with css, and move form on top of the collapse element:

```js
var viewModel = function() {
  this.formSubmit = function() {
    alert('submit');
  };

  $('#collapse1').on('show.bs.collapse', function(e) {
    alert('show content');
  }).on('hide.bs.collapse', function(e) {
    alert('hide content');
  });
};

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}
form {
  position: absolute;
  top: 7px;
  right: 80px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <form data-bind="submit: formSubmit">
    <input type="number" />
    <input type="submit" />
  </form>
  <div class="list-group-item list-group-item-danger" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse1">
    <div class="row form-inline">
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <strong>Collapse</strong>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Collapse content -->
  <div class="collapse" id="collapse1">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, cum etiam labitur diceret id, ex sale omnium neglegentur cum. Ad nec eirmod definiebas argumentum, eam te oratio disputando. In errem volumus cum, virtute platonem persequeris ei quo. Ex has reformidans consequuntur. Consetetur
      cotidieque et mea, in qui bonorum blandit. Nemore essent his an. Te hinc wisi consulatu usu, fuisset conceptam ius cu. Eam id mazim altera argumentum. At ridens moderatius his, in posse tollit moderatius vim, in vel dico recteque. Cum illum dissentias
      in, ex stet aliquip salutatus eum.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I updated jsfiddle, as of misleading listeners bound to the element itself. If you take a look at the collapse plugin (presented in the updated jsfiddle), you can tell that the click-handler is bound to the document, not the element itself. The event is indeed bubbling, but shouldn't the knockout submit-event be fired first if you click the submit-button? Since the submit-handler is bound to the element, and closest parent from the point of origin?

Comment: This should help clarify that http://javascript.info/tutorial/bubbling-and-capturing